# Unix Shell Script Syntax for if and grep and -gt

Tags: shell, scripting, if-statement, grep

I am using below code to copy the files. I am getting error at if statement..please help...
$1 is a number which will be searched in $j which is a file... i want to copy the file if there is some record otherwise nothing will be done...

```
for j in $2/$file_z
do
 if ``grep $1 $j | wc -l` -gt 0`
 then
  echo $j
  cp $j $3
 fi
done
```

Comment: Please be sure to include the actual error message in the future; Igor did a good job finding it this time :) but the actual error is sometimes not so clear.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in your script:

- Nested `backticks` are not allowed.
- `$2/$file_z` instead of `$(<$2/$file_z)`

Fixed:

```
for j in `<$2/$file_z`
do
 if grep -q "$1" "$j" > /dev/null
 # if grep "$1" "$j" > /dev/null # if your grep does not support -q
 then
  echo $j
  cp $j $3
 fi
done
```

More optimal:

```
for j in `<$2/$file_z`
do
 grep -l "$1" "$j" /dev/null && cp $j $3
done
```

`grep` itself can print the name of the file.

The same you can write also without `for`:

```
cp -v $(grep -l "$1" `<$2/$file_z`) $3
```

The command makes the same as your entire script.

Comment: Forget bacticks, that's deprecated in favor of `$( )` form. As you said, backticks don't support nested elements.

Comment: Thanks Igor, but it is giving me the following error. grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: I want to copy the file if $1 (number parameter) exists in $j(path/file) but your statement will evaluate if there is some record in it?

Comment: @Dogar: use `grep ... > /dev/null` when your grep does not support `-q`

Comment: bro, it is not working on my side, saying cannot open the file at line for j in `<$2/$file_z` ??

Comment: You shell is really old/specific. Ok. Than use `for j in $(cat $2/$file_z)`

Comment: `< file` is an idiom which conflicts with the sh standard.  shells that support it as a synonym for `cat file` are non-conformant.  `for j in $( cat file )` is the wrong replacement.  Use `while read j; do ...; done < file` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
for j in $(<$2/$file_z); do
    echo "$1" | grep &>/dev/null "$j" && cp "$j" "$3"
done
```

This is not portable :

```
grep -q
```

This is why I use `grep &>/dev/null` instead =)

Comment: Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
./script.sh[14]: 87346346832:  not found
this is coming now...

Comment: Thanks SPUTNICK...it is somehow working for me now...i will mold it...Thank you...:-)

Comment: Turns out `grep -q` is actually standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html  It is arguably slightly less portable, but is standard.  On the other hand `&>` as a redirection operator is not portable, and arguably conflicts with the standard!

Comment: Dogar, when people appreciate response here, they upvote & accept questions ;) This is the stackoverflow way to say thanks.